# Writing Image metadata in png image using pngj

Tags: java, io, png, metadata

Hi I am writing some custom meta data in png image using PNGJ.

I am able to write the meta data using PngJWriter at server side and able to read metadata using PngJ Reader at client side.

But if i save the image on local disk and try to read the meta data using javax.imageio.* classes I am not able to read the meta data inside image.

I tried to read using http://www.extractmetadata.com/ but still it is not working.

Below is the code I used to write it.

```
 public synchronized static byte[] writeMetaDataInImageUsingPngJ(byte[] imageData, String key,                                                                  String metaData)
{
    InputStream image = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
    PngReader reader = new PngReader(image);
    OutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PngWriter writer = new PngWriter(outStream, reader.imgInfo);
    // instruct the writer to copy all ancillary chunks from source
    writer.copyChunksFrom(reader.getChunksList(),      ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE);
    // add a new textual chunk (can also be done after writing the rows)

    writer.getMetadata().setText(key, metaData);
    // copy all rows
    for (int row = 0; row < reader.imgInfo.rows; row++ )
    {
        IImageLine l1 = reader.readRow();
        writer.writeRow(l1);
    }

    reader.end();
    writer.end();
    return ((ByteArrayOutputStream) outStream).toByteArray();

}
```

how to make sure that users can read meta data using normal libraries if I write using it PNGJ.

Comment: Can you share one of those PNG files with a textual chunk that is not recognized by http://www.extractmetadata.com/ ? Did you try with TweakPNG ?

Comment: yeah i tried with tweakPNG and it is working . @leonbloy